# Call Mono.TextTemplating from .Net Core console application

Tags: .net-core, mono, t4

I already installed the NuGet Mono.TextTemplating package into my project, but I didnt find any example to use call it from my application. I created templates, and would like to call the generator from my code with parameter.

Any advice? Is there any Mono.TextTemplating API documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just looking at the github page of [Mono.TextTemplating](https://github.com/mono/t4) in the readme section it says that the T4 documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017). It has multiple subsections with examples explaining it. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find official document, but you can refer to the [usage code](https://github.com/mono/t4/blob/master/TextTransform/TextTransform.cs).
And, basic usage like this:

```
string inputFile = "TextTemplate1.tt"; // define your T4 template first
string outputFile = "outputfile";
var generator = new TemplateGenerator ();
generator.ProcessTemplate (inputFile, outputFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up all the answers and references above I think here is how to start.

1. Install [Mono.TextTemplating](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.TextTemplating/) NuGet package.
2. Grab T4 template example from [this page](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/four-ways-to-generate-code-in-c-including-source-generators-in-net-5-9e6817db425) and save it as C:\TEMP\Mono-Templates\MyTemplate1.tt (file content's below).
3. Borrow code from lumen and run it. You'll get MyTemplate1Output.html file.
4. Now study more about [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates) and play.

P.S. MS introduced [C# Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) for .NET 5 as a new way of generation.

Code snippet:

```cs
string inputFile = @"C:\TEMP\Mono-Templates\MyTemplate1.tt";
string outputFile = @"C:\TEMP\Mono-Templates\MyTemplate1Output.html";
var generator = new Mono.TextTemplating.TemplateGenerator();
generator.ProcessTemplate(inputFile, outputFile);
if (generator.Errors.HasErrors)
{
    var consoleColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    foreach (var error in generator.Errors)
        Console.WriteLine (error);
    Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
}
```

File C:\TEMP\Mono-Templates\MyTemplate1.tt :

```html
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<html><body>
<h1>Sales for Previous Month</h2>
<table>
    <# for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
       { #>
         <tr><td>Test name <#= i #> </td>
             <td>Test value <#= i * i #> </td> </tr>
    <# } #>
 </table>
This report is Company Confidential.
</body></html>
```

Result file - MyTemplate1Output.html

```html
<html><body>
<h1>Sales for Previous Month</h2>
<table>
             <tr><td>Test name 1 </td>
             <td>Test value 1 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 2 </td>
             <td>Test value 4 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 3 </td>
             <td>Test value 9 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 4 </td>
             <td>Test value 16 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 5 </td>
             <td>Test value 25 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 6 </td>
             <td>Test value 36 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 7 </td>
             <td>Test value 49 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 8 </td>
             <td>Test value 64 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 9 </td>
             <td>Test value 81 </td> </tr>
             <tr><td>Test name 10 </td>
             <td>Test value 100 </td> </tr>
     </table>
This report is Company Confidential.
</body></html>
```